# Replace array values inside a document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection which looks something like this:

```
{
    paymentType: [1,2]     
}
```

Using aggregation framework, I'm looking for a way to replace the values with certain string, for example 1 = A, 2 = B so that the final result look slike that:

```
{
    paymentType: ['A','B']
}
```

I'm also using mongodb 2.4.

Please help,
Thanks!

Comment: I tried some combinations of $push and $map but had no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregation framework will never change the collection is acts on. The aggregation pipeline produces new documents (which are usually temporary and just piped out to the client). The simplest way to do this is just to grab each doc and replace the values, then update the field. Here's some code that has all the basic ideas:

```
> db.stuff.find({}, { "_id" : 1, "paymentType" : 1 }).forEach(function(doc) {
    var new_paymentType = []
    doc.paymentType.forEach(function(val) {
        if (val === 1) new_paymentType.push("A")
        if (val === 2) new_paymentType.push("B")
    })
    db.stuff.update({ "_id" : doc._id }, { "$set" : { "paymentType" : new_paymentType } })
})
```